# Docker daemon stops on multiple systems at the same time

Tags: docker, crash, daemon

I have a situation where multiple docker daemons stopped on separate AWS instances in relatively close time frame (all in the same 45 minutes, two in the same 10 minutes).

There appears

Stopping Docker Application Container Engine...

in the logs without any previous event.

It is followed by

level=info msg="Processing signal 'terminated'"
level=info msg="ignoring event" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"

and finally

Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.

after what Docker Daemon has to be started manually.

It happened before in one system but now it appeared in 3 systems simultaneously.

Application logs do not indicate anything suspicious.

Does anybody have similar experience? I am wondering at the moment what steps I should take to have more information during next such event.

Comment: I had the same problem today! And it has happened before around a month or two ago. I'm also on AWS and it happened across multiple instances and AWS accounts. Let me guess, it happened around 6-7AM? Similar issue posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65090971/docker-daemon-unexpectedly-exits

Comment: Yes, 6-7AM in eu-west-1.

Comment: I'm in eu-west-2!

Comment: ap-south-1 happened across multiple AWS accounts

Comment: Same here eu-west-1 at 6:26AM

Comment: This bug is now marked as critical and being tracked at: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/containerd/+bug/1870514

Comment: I am running multiple ubuntu18 VMs on our own openstack cluster and same thing happened around 6:51 UTC - not all servers were affected, but completely unrelated servers went down simultaneously so maybe something to do docker's internal scheduling system to be blamed? Also, all of the machines that went down were running mongo server as the primary node with in our production and test mongo replica set.. So it could be something related to mongo.. also

Comment: Looks like the automatic upgrade system, located in the "unattended-upgrades" package, installed  "containerd" upgrade that triggered a restart on that service. The containerd service restart caused docker daemon to crash. The fast but very unsafe workaround is to `apt-get remove unattended-upgrades` until this bug is fixed.